# gcc won't compile C++ code

Tags: c++

My code won't compile and I don't understand the cryptic output from the compiler. Can you spot the error?

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector <std::string> myVar;                                                        
    return 0;
}
```

Then in bash:

```
$ gcc main.cpp
/tmp/ccvmVBRq.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::deallocate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, unsigned long)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE10deallocateEPS6_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE10deallocateEPS6_m]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccvmVBRq.o: In function `void std::_Destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSt8_DestroyINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEvPT_[_ZSt8_DestroyINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEvPT_]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/ccvmVBRq.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Try g++ instead.

Comment: g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 or g++ main.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is C++ code, so you have to compile it with `g++`. Try:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
```